# How to echo specific key value from an object into an array value?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, object

I am trying to create a multidimensional array using data from some other arrays and objects. This is my php code:

```
<?php

    $items = $cck->getItems();

    $out = array();
    foreach( $items as $item ) {
        $out[] = array( 
                        "art_id" => $item->getValue('art_id'),
                        "art_title" => $item->getValue('art_title'),
                        "urun_resmi_fieldx" => $item->getValue('urun_resmi_fieldx')

                        );
     } 
     ?>
    <pre><?php print_r($out); ?></pre>
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [art_id] => 308
            [art_title] => 3D Katı Modelleme
            [urun_resmi_fieldx] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [art_id] => 311
            [art_title] => Dişli paslanmaz çelik kollektörler
            [urun_resmi_fieldx] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [value] => images/311/urun.jpg
                            [image_title] => urun.jpg
                            [image_alt] => urun.jpg
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [value] => images/311/slide-1.jpg
                            [image_title] => slide-1
                            [image_alt] => slide-1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I need to echo only value of [value] from the sddClass Objects for [urun_resmi_fieldx], I don't want to output [image_title] [image_alt] but I don't know how. When I try the code below I can get a specific row correctly but I don't know how many rows there will be.

```
"urun_resmi_fieldx" => $item->getValue('urun_resmi_fieldx')["0"]->value
```

This is the output I need:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [art_id] => 308
            [art_title] => 3D Katı Modelleme
            [urun_resmi_fieldx] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [art_id] => 311
            [art_title] => Dişli paslanmaz çelik kollektörler
            [urun_resmi_fieldx] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [value] => images/311/urun.jpg
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [value] => images/311/slide-1.jpg
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

My question is how I can loop this [value]s from sddClass Objects into array value.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

> I need to echo only value of [value] from the sddClass Objects for [urun_resmi_fieldx]...

**Solution:**

```
// Suppose $out is the original array
foreach($out as $value){
    if(count($value['urun_resmi_fieldx'])){
        foreach($value['urun_resmi_fieldx'] as $v){
            echo $v->value . "<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

**Edited:**

Based on your requirement, the solution would be like this:

```
foreach($out as $key => $value){
    if(count($value['urun_resmi_fieldx'])){
        foreach($value['urun_resmi_fieldx'] as $k => $v){
            $out[$key]['urun_resmi_fieldx'][$k] = (object)array('value' => $v->value);
        }
    }
}

// display $out array
var_dump($out);
```

Comment: foreach does not work as array value. $items is the source array, $out is output array.

Comment: @MelihTaş *foreach does not work as array value*, what do you mean by that? And did you run your application with this code snippet?

Comment: Yes I tried but $items is object, gives me this error. Fatal error: Cannot use object of type CCK_Item as array in C:\wamp\www\meka\templates\seb_json\positions\json\list\json.php on line 46

Comment: @MelihTaş That's where the problem lies, you're passing `$items` to the `foreach` loop. Pass the array `$out` to the loop, I've stated this thing in my answer also.

Comment: @MelihTaş I've updated my answer. Please see the **edited** section of my answer. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Comment: After I applied array_filter to my code, your code started working. "urun_resmi_fieldx" => array_filter($item->getValue('urun_resmi_fieldx'))

Comment: Output is this: [scalar] => images/311/urun.jpg Can you modify the code to output correct key?

Comment: @MelihTaş Why did you use `array_filter()`? Do `var_dump($out);`, post the ouput on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) and give me it's link here.

Comment: Sorry my fault, it works with or without array_filter. I was trying many things at the same time. Here is the output: http://pastebin.com/4aXAm16s Please look at index[5]

Comment: @MelihTaş You have to change this line `$out[$key]['urun_resmi_fieldx'][$k] = (object)$v->value;`. I've updated my answer. Please see the **edited** section of my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Suggestion:

```
<?php

    $items      = $cck->getItems();
    $out        = array();
    $uRun       = array();
    $counter    = 0;

    foreach( $items as $item ) {
        $uRun[] = $item->getValue('urun_resmi_fieldx');
        $out[]  = array(
          "art_id"              => $item->getValue('art_id'),
          "art_title"           => $item->getValue('art_title'),
          "urun_resmi_fieldx"   => $uRun[$counter]

        );
        $counter++;
    }
    //

     ?>
    <pre><?php print_r($uRun); //PRINTS THE "URUN_RESMI_FIELDX" OBJECT....?></pre>
    <pre><?php //print_r($out); ?></pre>

    <!-- PRINTS A NUMERICALLY INDEXED ARRAY OF OBJECTS REPRESENTING THE URUN_RESMI_FIELDX OBJECT -->
    Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [value] => images/311/urun.jpg
                        [image_title] => urun.jpg
                        [image_alt] => urun.jpg
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [value] => images/311/slide-1.jpg
                        [image_title] => slide-1
                        [image_alt] => slide-1
                    )

            )
```

Since this urum_resmi_fieldx Object contains an Array of Image Data, you could as well loop through the Array and access the properties you desire, like so:

```
    <?php
        $htmlPhotos = "<div class='image-box'>";
        foreach($uRun as $intKey=>$objPix){
            $htmlPhotos .= "<img alt= '" . $objPix->image_alt . "' title='" . $objPix->image_title . "' src='" . $objPix->value .  "' class='thumbnail' />";
        }
        $htmlPhotos .= "</div>";
        //DISPLAY ALL IMAGES ASSOCIATED WITH THIS ARTICLE/ITEM...
        echo $htmlPhotos;
```

Finally in summary; here is what may be possible:

```
<?php

    //AND HERE IS HOW YOUR DISPLAY MIGHT TYPICALLY LOOK LIKE:


    $items      = $cck->getItems();
    $out        = array();
    $uRun       = array();
    $counter    = 0;
    $output     = "<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='pdt-table' />";
    $output    .= "<thead class='pdt-table-head'>";
    $output    .= "<tr>";
    $output    .= "<th class='pdt-head-cel'><p class='emphasis'>Article Title</p></th>";
    $output    .= "<th class='pdt-head-cel'><p class='emphasis'>Article ID</p></th>";
    $output    .= "<th class='pdt-head-cel'><p class='emphasis'>Article Images</p></th>";
    $output    .= "</tr>";
    $output    .= "</thead>";
    $output    .= "<tbody>";

    foreach( $items as $item ) {
        $uRun[]     = $item->getValue('urun_resmi_fieldx');
        $out[]      = array(
          "art_id"              => $item->getValue('art_id'),
          "art_title"           => $item->getValue('art_title'),
          "urun_resmi_fieldx"   => $uRun[$counter]

        );
        $output    .= "<tr class='pdt-row'>";
        $output    .= "<td class='pdt-cell'>" . $item->getValue("art_title")    . "</td>";
        $output    .= "<td class='pdt-cell'>" . $item->getValue("art_id")       . "</td>";
        $output    .= "<td class='pdt-cell'>";

        $htmlPhotos = "<div class='image-box'>";
        foreach($uRun[$counter] as $intKey=>$objPix){
            $htmlPhotos .= "<img alt= '" . $objPix->image_alt . "' title='" . $objPix->image_title . "' src='" . $objPix->value .  "' class='thumbnail' />";
        }
        $htmlPhotos .= "</div>";
        $output     .= $htmlPhotos;
        $output     .= "</td>";
        $output     .= "</tr>";
        $counter++;
    }
    $output    .= "</tbody>";   
    $output    .= "</table>";   


    //DISPLAY ALL ARTICLES/ITEMS IN A TABLE (INCL. ASSOCIATED ITEM-IMAGES)
    echo $output;
```

Comment: "art_id" and "urun_resmi_fieldx" are not on the same level, so looping them in same foreach does not do what I want. BTW I do not neet html, my output will be json.